# statistics metrics or machine learning methods to quantify the relationship between a point and a group

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, descriptive-statistics, anomaly-detection

There are several data groups:

```
A1 = { A11, A12, A13, …, A1n}
A2 = {A21, A22, A23, …, A2n}
..
…
…
Am = {Am1, Am2, Am3, …, Amn}
```

Here `{ Aij, i = 1:m}`shares the same types of attribute j.
I would like to quantify the “position” of Aij in the group of Ai.  Naturally, I can use rank to measure it. For instance, A1j ranks as top one in group A1; A2j ranks as third in group A2; Amj ranks as third in group Am. Then I can say A1j seems abnormal in terms of its relationship with its group Aj. 
I would like to know are there any more systematic statistical/machine learning methods to handle this kind of scenario?